# Django Settings folder ImportError

Tags: python, django

I am replacing the Django settings file for a folder of different settings. The directory of the structure looks like this:

```
    .
    ├── manage.py
    ├── media
    ├── quito_events
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── settings
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── base.py
    │   ├── ci.py
    │   ├── local.py
    │   ├── production.py
    │   ├── staging.py
    │   └── test.py
    ├── static
    ├── templates
    └── users
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── models.py
        ├── tests.py
        └── views.py
```

When I try to run:

```
django-admin.py shell --settings=quito_events.settings.local


            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Users/eduardo/.virtualenvs/quito_events/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
                management.execute_from_command_line()
              File "/Users/eduardo/.virtualenvs/quito_events/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
                utility.execute()
              File "/Users/eduardo/.virtualenvs/quito_events/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
                self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
              File "/Users/eduardo/.virtualenvs/quito_events/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 263, in fetch_command
                app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
              File "/Users/eduardo/.virtualenvs/quito_events/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 109, in get_commands
                apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
              File "/Users/eduardo/.virtualenvs/quito_events/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
                self._setup(name)
              File "/Users/eduardo/.virtualenvs/quito_events/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
                self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
              File "/Users/eduardo/.virtualenvs/quito_events/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
                raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
            ImportError: Could not import settings 'quito_events.settings.local' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named quito_events.settings.local
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: quito_events.settings.local file not exists!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you shuld use:

```
python manage.py shell --settings=settings.local
```

Answer (score 2):

You can switch to use manage.py, e.g.

```
python manage.py shell --settings=quito_events.settings.local
```

or use django-admin.py with specified project path, e.g.

```
django-admin.py shell --pythonpath=your_project_path --settings=quito_events.settings.local
```